# Multiple <select> elements

Tags: html

I'm trying to create html (dynamically) which has multiple select elements, but not all of them appear to be displayed. Here's a minimal example:

```
<html>
<body>
   <select/>
   <select/>
</body>
</html>
```

This renders as a single select box in all the browsers I've tried. If I add more selects, I get more select boxes, but never as many as I ask for. Can someone explain what is going on?

Comment: There are no values and you immediately closed the `select` tags.

Comment: `select `need `option`s

Comment: You're only getting one because they need opening AND closing tags.  They cannot be self-closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are not closing the select tag correctly, it should be like this:

```
<select></select>
<select></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some values to your script like this example:

```
<html>
<body>
    <select>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4">Option 4</option>
    </select>

    <select>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4">Option 4</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Don't close the tags directly like you did in your question. Not all tags are self-closed, like `select` isn't a self-closed tag because it need values/options to make it work.

Useful list of self-closing tags: http://xahlee.info/js/html5_non-closing_tag.html

Hope this will help you.